# How to fix namespace not being determined in new folders project?

Tags: php, configuration, namespaces, phpstorm

I upgraded from phpstorm7 to phpstorm8. Now, whenever I create a new PHP class in an existing folder, the namespace is inserted correctly. Yet when I create an empty folder and create in there a new class, the namespace is empty and I would have to manually add it.

In pictures:

1. Existing folder has the namespace:
   [image: Example of the namesapce being inserted for an existing folder]
2. New folder in the same project lacks the namespace.
   [image: Example of the namespace not being generated for a new folder]

How can I tell phpstorm to always autogenerate the current namespace?

Comment: It's hard to say what is wrong .. but most likely you do not have marked certain folders as Namespace roots. Please show screenshot of `Preferences | Directories` (since you are on Mac). **P.S.** You may also try `Code | Detect PSR-0 Namespace Roots` if you have not got them set up yet.

Comment: Will it help? -> http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/04/psr-0-psr-4-and-sourcetest-root-support-in-phpstorm-8-eap/

Comment: This is an old post, but since I ran into it, I figured other people might too. I managed to fix this issue by going into `Settings > Project: xxx > Directories` and clicking the little 'P' next to my `src` directory and setting a root namespace for my project.

Comment: @RobinKanters Thanks for pointing that out. You may add that as an answer for me to upvote, even though it wasn't my original issue. I just ran into something similar where no matter what I tried the default namespace was always wrong in one project, and the solution provided in your comment helped.

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes PhpStorm doesn't correctly detect the appropriate namespace for your source directories.

You could try to fix this by going into `Settings > Project: xxx > Directories`, clicking the little 'P' next to your `src/` directory and setting a root namespace for your project.

[image]
*(you may not have as much directories listed in the right panel, depending on the complexity of your project)*

Comment: To do this automatically you can use setting called 'Synchronize IDE Settings with composer.json'. It supports PSR-0 and PSR-4.
Be aware that enabling this option affects some other settings (however they're useful) too.